# Why asterisk not properly working with android sip client?

Tags: android, voip, asterisk

Asterisk= 1.8.11.0

Android= 2.3/4.0.3

Android Sip client=Native Android sip client/sipdemo

When i call from my pc using zoiper/xlite to android (native android sip client) now i can hear audio from both sides but when i make call from android to pc (zoiper/xlite) i cannot hear anything on android.
On the other hand i have tested this scenario on elastix (which also uses asterisk 1.8.11.0) with no problem in audio.
pc(zoiper) ip 192.168.15.27
android ip 192.168.15.71
asterisk server ip 192.168.15.118

**Sip debug when calling from android to zoiper .**

```
<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.15.71:45616 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK5996b0d9;rport=5060;received=192.168.15.118
From: "asterisk" <sip:asterisk@192.168.15.118>;tag=as05233e7d
To: <sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp>
Call-ID: 14151c2d29c039983aa449b56ce419e0@192.168.15.118:5060
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
--- (7 headers 0 lines) ---
Really destroying SIP dialog '14151c2d29c039983aa449b56ce419e0@192.168.15.118:5060' Method: OPTIONS

<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.15.71:45616 --->
OPTIONS sip:192.168.15.118 SIP/2.0
Call-ID: 5f7229b44e43a9e0eeaccabafd9a1e4f@192.168.15.71
CSeq: 7757 OPTIONS
From: "211" <sip:211@192.168.15.118>;tag=1758376458
To: "211" <sip:211@192.168.15.118>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.71:45616;branch=z9hG4bK6c57f04e92e9e34153367ca0e6e29675353134;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
User-Agent: SIPAUA/0.1.001
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
--- (9 headers 0 lines) ---
Looking for s in default (domain 192.168.15.118)

<--- Transmitting (NAT) to 192.168.15.71:45616 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.71:45616;branch=z9hG4bK6c57f04e92e9e34153367ca0e6e29675353134;received=192.168.15.71;rport=45616
From: "211" <sip:211@192.168.15.118>;tag=1758376458
To: "211" <sip:211@192.168.15.118>;tag=as6a8e1b47
Call-ID: 5f7229b44e43a9e0eeaccabafd9a1e4f@192.168.15.71
CSeq: 7757 OPTIONS
Server: Asterisk PBX 1.8.11.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:192.168.15.118:5060>
Accept: application/sdp
Content-Length: 0


<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.15.71:45616 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK1ecea84c;rport=5060;received=192.168.15.118
From: "asterisk" <sip:asterisk@192.168.15.118>;tag=as167765df
To: <sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp>
Call-ID: 5f4d210800aa07065fd35fba215e9783@192.168.15.118:5060
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
--- (7 headers 0 lines) ---
Really destroying SIP dialog '5f4d210800aa07065fd35fba215e9783@192.168.15.118:5060' Method: OPTIONS
Really destroying SIP dialog '5e5f98ad4818911a86d4b438d054e39f@192.168.15.71' Method: OPTIONS
Reliably Transmitting (NAT) to 192.168.15.71:45616:
OPTIONS sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK15f7593b;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "asterisk" <sip:asterisk@192.168.15.118>;tag=as53340ecf
To: <sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp>
Contact: <sip:asterisk@192.168.15.118:5060>
Call-ID: 3c9da88024211f4b2ad1f3af2b2acd73@192.168.15.118:5060
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 1.8.11.0
Date: Sat, 12 Jan 2013 19:44:34 GMT
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Length: 0


---

<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.15.71:45616 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK15f7593b;rport=5060;received=192.168.15.118
From: "asterisk" <sip:asterisk@192.168.15.118>;tag=as53340ecf
To: <sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp>
Call-ID: 3c9da88024211f4b2ad1f3af2b2acd73@192.168.15.118:5060
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
--- (7 headers 0 lines) ---
Really destroying SIP dialog '3c9da88024211f4b2ad1f3af2b2acd73@192.168.15.118:5060' Method: OPTIONS

<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.15.71:45616 --->
BYE sip:215@192.168.15.118:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.71:45616;branch=z9hG4bKad00f5add2a1f2e940a91e9a3f827b26353134
CSeq: 5511 BYE
From: "211" <sip:211@192.168.15.118>;tag=2465683119
To: <sip:215@192.168.15.118>;tag=as573c52b3
Call-ID: d188757cd6c044783fd413d11f8a982f@192.168.15.71
Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,SUBSCRIBE,NOTIFY,INFO,PUBLISH
Supported: replaces,timer
Max-Forwards: 70
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
--- (10 headers 0 lines) ---
Sending to 192.168.15.71:45616 (NAT)
Scheduling destruction of SIP dialog 'd188757cd6c044783fd413d11f8a982f@192.168.15.71' in 6400 ms (Method: BYE)

<--- Transmitting (NAT) to 192.168.15.71:45616 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.71:45616;branch=z9hG4bKad00f5add2a1f2e940a91e9a3f827b26353134;received=192.168.15.71;rport=45616
From: "211" <sip:211@192.168.15.118>;tag=2465683119
To: <sip:215@192.168.15.118>;tag=as573c52b3
Call-ID: d188757cd6c044783fd413d11f8a982f@192.168.15.71
CSeq: 5511 BYE
Server: Asterisk PBX 1.8.11.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Length: 0
<------------>
Scheduling destruction of SIP dialog '0d06690561757f98637241394cc8dbba@192.168.15.118:5060' in 6400 ms (Method: INVITE)
set_destination: Parsing <sip:215@115.167.21.82:5060;rinstance=49cb21467969bef8;transport=UDP> for address/port to send to
set_destination: set destination to 115.167.21.82:5060
Reliably Transmitting (NAT) to 192.168.15.27:5060:
BYE sip:215@115.167.21.82:5060;rinstance=49cb21467969bef8;transport=UDP SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK1500d2f6;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "device" <sip:211@192.168.15.118>;tag=as404f0eb0
To: <sip:215@115.167.21.82:5060;rinstance=49cb21467969bef8;transport=UDP>;tag=96055240
Call-ID: 0d06690561757f98637241394cc8dbba@192.168.15.118:5060
CSeq: 103 BYE
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 1.8.11.0
X-Asterisk-HangupCause: Normal Clearing
X-Asterisk-HangupCauseCode: 16
Content-Length: 0
---
== Spawn extension (incoming-calls-wildcard, 215, 1) exited non-zero on 'SIP/211-00000008'
Retransmitting #1 (NAT) to 192.168.15.27:5060:
BYE sip:215@115.167.21.82:5060;rinstance=49cb21467969bef8;transport=UDP SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK1500d2f6;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "device" <sip:211@192.168.15.118>;tag=as404f0eb0
To: <sip:215@115.167.21.82:5060;rinstance=49cb21467969bef8;transport=UDP>;tag=96055240
Call-ID: 0d06690561757f98637241394cc8dbba@192.168.15.118:5060
CSeq: 103 BYE
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 1.8.11.0
X-Asterisk-HangupCause: Normal Clearing
X-Asterisk-HangupCauseCode: 16
Content-Length: 0
---
<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.15.27:5060 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK1500d2f6;rport=5060
Contact: <sip:215@115.167.21.82:5060;rinstance=49cb21467969bef8;transport=UDP>
To: <sip:215@115.167.21.82:5060;rinstance=49cb21467969bef8;transport=UDP>;tag=96055240
From: "device"<sip:211@192.168.15.118>;tag=as404f0eb0
Call-ID: 0d06690561757f98637241394cc8dbba@192.168.15.118:5060
CSeq: 103 BYE
User-Agent: Zoiper for Windows 2.39 r16838
Content-Length: 0
<------------->
-- (9 headers 0 lines) ---
Really destroying SIP dialog '0d06690561757f98637241394cc8dbba@192.168.15.118:5060' Method: INVITE

<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.15.27:5060 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK1500d2f6;rport=5060
Contact: <sip:215@115.167.21.82:5060;rinstance=49cb21467969bef8;transport=UDP>
To: <sip:215@115.167.21.82:5060;rinstance=49cb21467969bef8;transport=UDP>;tag=96055240
From: "device"<sip:211@192.168.15.118>;tag=as404f0eb0
Call-ID: 0d06690561757f98637241394cc8dbba@192.168.15.118:5060
CSeq: 103 BYE
User-Agent: Zoiper for Windows 2.39 r16838
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
-- (9 headers 0 lines) ---
Reliably Transmitting (NAT) to 192.168.15.71:45616:
OPTIONS sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK30d9d70f;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "asterisk" <sip:asterisk@192.168.15.118>;tag=as4f0724aa
To: <sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp>
Contact: <sip:asterisk@192.168.15.118:5060>
Call-ID: 05f27bf10f0a0759637b90252dc4366a@192.168.15.118:5060
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 1.8.11.0
Date: Sat, 12 Jan 2013 19:44:37 GMT
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Length: 0


---

<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.15.71:45616 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK30d9d70f;rport=5060;received=192.168.15.118
From: "asterisk" <sip:asterisk@192.168.15.118>;tag=as4f0724aa
To: <sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp>
Call-ID: 05f27bf10f0a0759637b90252dc4366a@192.168.15.118:5060
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
--- (7 headers 0 lines) ---
Really destroying SIP dialog '05f27bf10f0a0759637b90252dc4366a@192.168.15.118:5060' Method: OPTIONS

<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.15.71:45616 --->
OPTIONS sip:192.168.15.118 SIP/2.0
Call-ID: a5a311df861221d42844a8c485d4fee8@192.168.15.71
CSeq: 5815 OPTIONS
From: "211" <sip:211@192.168.15.118>;tag=3109248316
To: "211" <sip:211@192.168.15.118>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.71:45616;branch=z9hG4bK1e09e6f6c30b4b74ddc93c590abd3383353134;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
User-Agent: SIPAUA/0.1.001
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
--- (9 headers 0 lines) ---
Looking for s in default (domain 192.168.15.118)

<--- Transmitting (NAT) to 192.168.15.71:45616 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.71:45616;branch=z9hG4bK1e09e6f6c30b4b74ddc93c590abd3383353134;received=192.168.15.71;rport=45616
From: "211" <sip:211@192.168.15.118>;tag=3109248316
To: "211" <sip:211@192.168.15.118>;tag=as51223faf
Call-ID: a5a311df861221d42844a8c485d4fee8@192.168.15.71
CSeq: 5815 OPTIONS
Server: Asterisk PBX 1.8.11.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:192.168.15.118:5060>
Accept: application/sdp
Content-Length: 0


<------------>
Scheduling destruction of SIP dialog 'a5a311df861221d42844a8c485d4fee8@192.168.15.71' in 32000 ms (Method: OPTIONS)
Reliably Transmitting (NAT) to 192.168.15.71:45616:
OPTIONS sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK1f8e44dc;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "asterisk" <sip:asterisk@192.168.15.118>;tag=as7a9a1ea3
To: <sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp>
Contact: <sip:asterisk@192.168.15.118:5060>
Call-ID: 7ebcafc7159379fd047075a85c424588@192.168.15.118:5060
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 1.8.11.0
Date: Sat, 12 Jan 2013 19:44:41 GMT
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Length: 0


---

<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.15.71:45616 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK1f8e44dc;rport=5060;received=192.168.15.118
From: "asterisk" <sip:asterisk@192.168.15.118>;tag=as7a9a1ea3
To: <sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp>
Call-ID: 7ebcafc7159379fd047075a85c424588@192.168.15.118:5060
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
--- (7 headers 0 lines) ---
Really destroying SIP dialog '7ebcafc7159379fd047075a85c424588@192.168.15.118:5060' Method: OPTIONS
Really destroying SIP dialog 'd188757cd6c044783fd413d11f8a982f@192.168.15.71' Method: BYE
Really destroying SIP dialog 'a81e6a5f591141abd73f9dad478a6b56@192.168.15.71' Method: OPTIONS
Reliably Transmitting (NAT) to 192.168.15.71:45616:
OPTIONS sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK017f2b0a;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "asterisk" <sip:asterisk@192.168.15.118>;tag=as5367b37c
To: <sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp>
Contact: <sip:asterisk@192.168.15.118:5060>
Call-ID: 1f5a66a10c6dc1e4126a681d2001b173@192.168.15.118:5060
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 1.8.11.0
Date: Sat, 12 Jan 2013 19:44:44 GMT
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Length: 0

---
<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.15.71:45616 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK017f2b0a;rport=5060;received=192.168.15.118
From: "asterisk" <sip:asterisk@192.168.15.118>;tag=as5367b37c
To: <sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp>
Call-ID: 1f5a66a10c6dc1e4126a681d2001b173@192.168.15.118:5060
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
--- (7 headers 0 lines) ---
Really destroying SIP dialog '1f5a66a10c6dc1e4126a681d2001b173@192.168.15.118:5060' Method: OPTIONS
```

**When calling from pc (zoiper) to android**

```
<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.15.71:45616 --->
BYE sip:215@192.168.15.118:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.71:45616;branch=z9hG4bKe2f448b90c482342407298e309be5aed353134
CSeq: 1 BYE
From: <sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp>;tag=4162167884
To: "device" <sip:215@192.168.15.118>;tag=as5805dc66
Call-ID: 2732e4564ce8534c5765a456045a9960@192.168.15.118:5060
Max-Forwards: 70
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
--- (8 headers 0 lines) ---
Sending to 192.168.15.71:45616 (NAT)
Scheduling destruction of SIP dialog '2732e4564ce8534c5765a456045a9960@192.168.15.118:5060' in 8576 ms (Method: BYE)

<--- Transmitting (NAT) to 192.168.15.71:45616 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.71:45616;branch=z9hG4bKe2f448b90c482342407298e309be5aed353134;received=192.168.15.71;rport=45616
From: <sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp>;tag=4162167884
To: "device" <sip:215@192.168.15.118>;tag=as5805dc66
Call-ID: 2732e4564ce8534c5765a456045a9960@192.168.15.118:5060
CSeq: 1 BYE
Server: Asterisk PBX 1.8.11.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Length: 0


<------------>
== Spawn extension (incoming-calls-wildcard, 211, 1) exited non-zero on 'SIP/215-0000000a'
Scheduling destruction of SIP dialog 'MDhhMTg1YjllYTUwZThlMmNiZTQwYTMzODYyZmEzNjk.' in 6400 ms (Method: ACK)
set_destination: Parsing <sip:215@115.167.21.82:5060;transport=UDP> for address/port to send to
set_destination: set destination to 115.167.21.82:5060
Reliably Transmitting (NAT) to 192.168.15.27:5060:
BYE sip:215@115.167.21.82:5060;transport=UDP SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK498da08b;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:211@192.168.15.118;transport=UDP>;tag=as10377813
To: <sip:215@192.168.15.118;transport=UDP>;tag=50312112
Call-ID: MDhhMTg1YjllYTUwZThlMmNiZTQwYTMzODYyZmEzNjk.
CSeq: 102 BYE
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 1.8.11.0
Proxy-Authorization: Digest username="215", realm="asterisk", algorithm=MD5, uri="sip:192.168.15.118", nonce="", response="c897390cc8e4f674d7e9cd1efa7319a6"
X-Asterisk-HangupCause: Normal Clearing
X-Asterisk-HangupCauseCode: 16
Content-Length: 0


---
Retransmitting #1 (NAT) to 192.168.15.27:5060:
BYE sip:215@115.167.21.82:5060;transport=UDP SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK498da08b;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:211@192.168.15.118;transport=UDP>;tag=as10377813
To: <sip:215@192.168.15.118;transport=UDP>;tag=50312112
Call-ID: MDhhMTg1YjllYTUwZThlMmNiZTQwYTMzODYyZmEzNjk.
CSeq: 102 BYE
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 1.8.11.0
Proxy-Authorization: Digest username="215", realm="asterisk", algorithm=MD5, uri="sip:192.168.15.118", nonce="", response="c897390cc8e4f674d7e9cd1efa7319a6"
X-Asterisk-HangupCause: Normal Clearing
X-Asterisk-HangupCauseCode: 16
Content-Length: 0


---

<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.15.27:5060 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK498da08b;rport=5060
Contact: <sip:215@115.167.21.82:5060;transport=UDP>
To: <sip:215@192.168.15.118;transport=UDP>;tag=50312112
From: <sip:211@192.168.15.118;transport=UDP>;tag=as10377813
Call-ID: MDhhMTg1YjllYTUwZThlMmNiZTQwYTMzODYyZmEzNjk.
CSeq: 102 BYE
User-Agent: Zoiper for Windows 2.39 r16838
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
--- (9 headers 0 lines) ---
SIP Response message for INCOMING dialog BYE arrived
Really destroying SIP dialog 'MDhhMTg1YjllYTUwZThlMmNiZTQwYTMzODYyZmEzNjk.' Method: ACK

<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.15.27:5060 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK498da08b;rport=5060
Contact: <sip:215@115.167.21.82:5060;transport=UDP>
To: <sip:215@192.168.15.118;transport=UDP>;tag=50312112
From: <sip:211@192.168.15.118;transport=UDP>;tag=as10377813
Call-ID: MDhhMTg1YjllYTUwZThlMmNiZTQwYTMzODYyZmEzNjk.
CSeq: 102 BYE
User-Agent: Zoiper for Windows 2.39 r16838
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
--- (9 headers 0 lines) ---
Reliably Transmitting (NAT) to 192.168.15.71:45616:
OPTIONS sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK01e7e47d;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "asterisk" <sip:asterisk@192.168.15.118>;tag=as73902c1e
To: <sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp>
Contact: <sip:asterisk@192.168.15.118:5060>
Call-ID: 7b77192d5d07c4bf5d0a82ab2c11c3c1@192.168.15.118:5060
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 1.8.11.0
Date: Sat, 12 Jan 2013 19:54:09 GMT
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Length: 0


---

<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.15.71:45616 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK01e7e47d;rport=5060;received=192.168.15.118
From: "asterisk" <sip:asterisk@192.168.15.118>;tag=as73902c1e
To: <sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp>
Call-ID: 7b77192d5d07c4bf5d0a82ab2c11c3c1@192.168.15.118:5060
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
--- (7 headers 0 lines) ---
Really destroying SIP dialog '7b77192d5d07c4bf5d0a82ab2c11c3c1@192.168.15.118:5060' Method: OPTIONS

<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.15.71:45616 --->
OPTIONS sip:192.168.15.118 SIP/2.0
Call-ID: c51761a244f0dc9639f87a5cf9af1b3f@192.168.15.71
CSeq: 9273 OPTIONS
From: "211" <sip:211@192.168.15.118>;tag=740019322
To: "211" <sip:211@192.168.15.118>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.71:45616;branch=z9hG4bK5ac51b5cca5ad84320fc342692fdbb2d353134;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
User-Agent: SIPAUA/0.1.001
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
--- (9 headers 0 lines) ---
Looking for s in default (domain 192.168.15.118)

<--- Transmitting (NAT) to 192.168.15.71:45616 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.71:45616;branch=z9hG4bK5ac51b5cca5ad84320fc342692fdbb2d353134;received=192.168.15.71;rport=45616
From: "211" <sip:211@192.168.15.118>;tag=740019322
To: "211" <sip:211@192.168.15.118>;tag=as1bed6ef2
Call-ID: c51761a244f0dc9639f87a5cf9af1b3f@192.168.15.71
CSeq: 9273 OPTIONS
Server: Asterisk PBX 1.8.11.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:192.168.15.118:5060>
Accept: application/sdp
Content-Length: 0

<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.15.71:45616 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK3c24b1cb;rport=5060;received=192.168.15.118
From: "asterisk" <sip:asterisk@192.168.15.118>;tag=as54c6581a
To: <sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp>
Call-ID: 7742af6c24e3e9a33efa0ba73051a29e@192.168.15.118:5060
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
--- (7 headers 0 lines) ---
Really destroying SIP dialog '7742af6c24e3e9a33efa0ba73051a29e@192.168.15.118:5060' Method: OPTIONS

<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.15.71:45616 --->
OPTIONS sip:192.168.15.118 SIP/2.0
Call-ID: 18347a0db6841423591b08250847a1e0@192.168.15.71
CSeq: 3824 OPTIONS
From: "211" <sip:211@192.168.15.118>;tag=841349553
To: "211" <sip:211@192.168.15.118>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.71:45616;branch=z9hG4bK79bb575a5d0f832291b861987849d9a2353134;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
User-Agent: SIPAUA/0.1.001
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
--- (9 headers 0 lines) ---
Looking for s in default (domain 192.168.15.118)


<------------->
--- (9 headers 0 lines) ---
Looking for s in default (domain 192.168.15.118)

<--- Transmitting (NAT) to 192.168.15.71:45616 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.71:45616;branch=z9hG4bK40d81d1686d23c9133e52f4180c2accb353134;received=192.168.15.71;rport=45616
From: "211" <sip:211@192.168.15.118>;tag=4017391219
To: "211" <sip:211@192.168.15.118>;tag=as52fe1845
Call-ID: 09809b7ed9a68b7f270f33f1d8de13dc@192.168.15.71
CSeq: 4619 OPTIONS
Server: Asterisk PBX 1.8.11.0
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
Contact: <sip:192.168.15.118:5060>
Accept: application/sdp
Content-Length: 0


<------------>
Scheduling destruction of SIP dialog '09809b7ed9a68b7f270f33f1d8de13dc@192.168.15.71' in 32000 ms (Method: OPTIONS)
Reliably Transmitting (NAT) to 192.168.15.71:45616:
OPTIONS sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK13b8cca8;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "asterisk" <sip:asterisk@192.168.15.118>;tag=as6e6638f8
To: <sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp>
Contact: <sip:asterisk@192.168.15.118:5060>
Call-ID: 76f6f373769041c3462ebb676641f1b7@192.168.15.118:5060
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 1.8.11.0
Date: Sat, 12 Jan 2013 19:54:31 GMT
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Length: 0


---

<--- SIP read from UDP:192.168.15.71:45616 --->
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK13b8cca8;rport=5060;received=192.168.15.118
From: "asterisk" <sip:asterisk@192.168.15.118>;tag=as6e6638f8
To: <sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp>
Call-ID: 76f6f373769041c3462ebb676641f1b7@192.168.15.118:5060
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0

<------------->
--- (7 headers 0 lines) ---
Really destroying SIP dialog '76f6f373769041c3462ebb676641f1b7@192.168.15.118:5060' Method: OPTIONS
Really destroying SIP dialog '9eeee094f46eec920ac462e291314bde@192.168.15.71' Method: OPTIONS
Reliably Transmitting (NAT) to 192.168.15.71:45616:
OPTIONS sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.15.118:5060;branch=z9hG4bK47a8a134;rport
Max-Forwards: 70
From: "asterisk" <sip:asterisk@192.168.15.118>;tag=as76426de6
To: <sip:211@192.168.15.71:45616;transport=udp>
Contact: <sip:asterisk@192.168.15.118:5060>
Call-ID: 3a98a25b41dc3b3e699ee4383669e984@192.168.15.118:5060
CSeq: 102 OPTIONS
User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 1.8.11.0
Date: Sat, 12 Jan 2013 19:54:34 GMT
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH
Supported: replaces, timer
Content-Length: 0
```

I am using asterisk on local network (LAN)....

**My dial plan in extensions.conf is:**

```
[incoming-calls-wildcard]

exten => _2XX,hint,(SIP/${EXTEN},,120)

exten => _2XX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN},,120)

exten => _2XX,n,Hangup
```

**My sip account is:**

```
[215]

deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0

secret=very123

dtmfmode=rfc2833

canreinvite=no

context=incoming-calls-wildcard

host=dynamic

type=friend

nat=yes

port=5060

qualify=yes

callgroup=

pickupgroup=

dial=SIP/215

mailbox=215@device

permit=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0

callerid=device <215>

callcounter=yes

faxdetect=no
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for every one in this forum for anticipating...I have manged to solve the problem...The two devices "xlite/zoiper" and "android native sip" client uses different default audio codecs.

default codec for xlite is BroadVoice-32

default codec for zoiper is GSM

default codec for android is G.711 uLaw

As these devices should use same codec while communicating with each other..In my scenario these devices were using different codecs which results in one way audio (when calling from android to xlite/zoiper).
While creating the SIP accounts in sip.conf while we can enforce two communicating clients to use same audio codec in following manner.

```
[211]
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
secret=123456
dtmfmode=rfc2833
canreinvite=no
context=incoming-calls-wildcard
host=dynamic
nat=yes
type=friend
port=5060
qualify=yes
callgroup=
pickupgroup=
permit=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
callcounter=yes
faxdetect=no
disallow=all    (disable default audio codec)
allow=ulaw   (allow uLaw audio codec)



[215]
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
secret=123456
dtmfmode=rfc2833
canreinvite=no
context=incoming-calls-wildcard
host=dynamic
nat=no
type=friend
port=5060
qualify=yes
callgroup=
pickupgroup=
permit=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
callcounter=yes
faxdetect=no
disallow=all    (disable default audio codec)
allow=ulaw   (allow uLaw audio codec)
```

We can also configure audio codec settings on client side by selecting the same audio codec on both sides..

Comment: I had the same problem trying to communicate a linphone client with a client that I wrote using pjsip. The call hanged after 32 seconds. I have been days on this. Thank you so much man!! You saved me!

Answer (score 0):

Well,

Configuration wise, it appear that your configuration is ok. However, what seems odd to me is the following IP address inside your trace - 115.167.21.82

Can you please elaborate what this IP address is? My assumption is that you are located behind a NAT firewall and this is your external IP address. In that case, look in /etc/asterisk/sip.conf for the "localnet" definition, and define your local network address range.

When working with Elastix, it is able to setup that one automatically - but when doing a manual install, you have to set that one up.

Nir S

Comment: First of all thanks for taking interest..I have tested the scenario by adding localnet in sip.conf file but it did not work....

Comment: If it is localnet or nat problem then why both parties can hear audio when calling from xlite/zoiper to xlite/zoiper ??

Comment: Thanks for anticipating...I have solved the problem and answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have nat issues:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+SIP+NAT+solutions

Comment: Thanks arheops for taking interest ..I actually don't agree that there is some nat issues..If there are nat problems then why both parties can hear audio when calling from xlite/zoiper/healink to xlite/zoiper/yelink..

Comment: Thanks for anticipating...I have solved the problem and answered my own question.