# Does my asterisk server need the same codecs as my mobile app?

Tags: android, iphone, asterisk, codec

Right now, both my android and iphone voip app is using the G711 codec.  My asterisk server is set up to allow ulaw codec, which i understand is the same as G711.

Now I want to start using the G729 codec on my android and iphone voip app. I've upgraded the the sip library on these apps to support this.

Do I also need to install a G729 codec on my asterisk server in order for my android and iphone voip app to talk to each other?

Comment: You may want to check the accepted answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300979/why-asterisk-not-properly-working-with-android-sip-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, you don't need install the G729 codec but need enable it in the sip.conf file for allow the codec pass-thru.

[Asterisk G.729 pass-thru](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+G.729+pass-thru)

The long one is: It depends on your requirements. Some features will demand decoding/transcoding to work and, in that case, you will need to install G729 codec in Asterisk, like:

- Direct PSTN termination (not through a sip trunking service);
- Direct connected extension (not SIP ATA/IAD)
- Voice conferencing
- Silence detection
- ...